# How to read a table from a .do file on a webpage?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Please help me out in this case. I want the list of districts and their formation year and dates from the local government directory in India. While, I have tried a number of codes but I am unable to read them. Can someone help me out with this?

The codes that I use are as follows -

```
> col_link = "https://lgdirectory.gov.in/"
> col_page= read_html(col_link)
```

There is a district hyperlink present on this webpage but when you click it there is a captcha that needs to be entered. If you enter this captcha the table that I need gets opened but the url appears as - https://lgdirectory.gov.in/globalviewdistrict.do

How to read the contents of the table? There is a PDF and a spreadsheet link present, but pdf is cut and spreadsheet does not have the 'View Details' column. I need the district name and the effective date, which appears when you click on the eye button under the view details column. Please help me out.

```
> col_link = "https://lgdirectory.gov.in/globalviewdistrict.do"
> col_page= read_html(col_link)
> col_table = col_page %>% html_nodes("table#view_district_table") %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
Error in .[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

If you remove .[[1]] from the above code and run the following code

```
> col_table = col_page %>% html_nodes("table#view_district_table") %>% html_table()
```

you get a empty list. Where am I going wrong. Can .do file be read into R or there is some other issue ?

Comment: Read in the excel data, then for every district details open  `https://lgdirectory.gov.in/globalviewDistrictDetail.do?globaldistrictId=603` where `603` is district ID and read in the effectve date.